# Proof that for every bounded open subset of a $n$-dimensional euclidean space, there exists a point in such space with the folowing condition?

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces

If $X=\Bbb R^n$ is equipped with the usual topology $\tau$ and the usual metric $d$, and we define the function $\pi_U:X\to X$ for every bounded $U\in\tau $ as

$$\pi_U(p)=\int_U d(x,p)dx$$

I need to prove that for every bounded $U\in\tau$ there exists a $p\in X$ such that for all $q\in X$ it holds that $\pi_U(p)<\pi_U(q)$ i.e. that $\pi_U$ has a unique point that attains its minimum value. I need to reach to a contradiction when defining two points with said property, but cannot find any, any help would be appreciated.

An example would be $\pi_X$ where $X$ is the 2d disk or radius $r$(the set of points such that its norm is less than $r$) centered at $(0,0)$, then $(0,0)$ is a point with said property. Same with a rectangle of length $2r$ centered at the origin.

Comment: Are you integrating with respect to the Lebesgue measure? If that's the case then wouldn't we have $\pi_K(p)=0$ for any $p\in\Bbb R^n$ if $K$ is a finite set?

Comment: @BigbearZzz But a finite set is not an open set in the usual topology.

Comment: But didn't you specify that $U$ is compact? How can $U$ be both compact and open?

Comment: @BigbearZzz $U$ should be closed, sorry.

Comment: Then what about the issue that I addressed? My $K$ is compact and hence closed, but clearly the minimum of $\pi_K$ is not unique.

Comment: @BigbearZzz But the compliment of a finite set is not in the usual topology, right? Or am I messing something up? What I mean is that $U$ is bounded and contains its boundary, so it can be riemann-integrated with a finite result. Maybe my terminology is not correct.

Comment: Why not? The complement of a finite set is clearly open. Any finite set $K$ is bounded and contains its boundary so you got the terminology right. The point is that the with the assumptions you gave, the statement you're trying to prove is simply false.

Comment: In every Hausdorff space @Garmekain finite sets are closed and their complement open.

Comment: I Edited the question to previous condition.

Comment: So now the question doesn't involve compactness at all?

Comment: @BigbearZzz No.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, seeing that you keep changing the question, did you get this statement from a book or is it some conjecture that you believe to be true?

Comment: @BigbearZzz It's the latter, because this resembles the "center of mass" of some points.

Comment: Then please don't keep changing the question when someone found a counter example. You should also mention this explicitly so the people know that the statement you're trying to prove may not be true.

Comment: This is much easier if you integrate the square of the distance function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in the general case. Suppose $n=1$ and $U=(-3,-1)\cup(1,3)$, clearly $U$ is an open bounded subset of $\Bbb R$. Then every value $-1<y<1$ of $\int_Ud(x,y)dx$ will yield the minimum value of the function, $8$, so $\pi_{(-3,-1)\cup(1,3)}$ has not a unique value that attains its minimum value, there are actually uncountable many of them.